# how to print window.navigator as json string nicely?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to print window.navigator as json string nicely ?

console.log(window.navigator) please don't suggest, I need it use in future in html body

JSON.stringify() doesn't work with window.navigator :=(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting it in new object like ,

```
var _navigator = {};
for (var i in window.navigator) _navigator[i] = navigator[i];
JSON.stringify(_navigator);
```